# Cannot query a DateTime column in Table Storage

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have inserted a column into table storage using formatDateTime() from within a Logic App and the correct value is entered and the column type is displayed as DateTime when I view the record:

[image]

However when I try to query on this field it defaults to string and even when I change it to DateTime it returns no results.

[image]

I have tried no formatting, standard formats and custom formats in the formatDateTime() but nothing will bring back results.  Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Comment: Hi, please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test, the value is still in "**String**" type but not "**DateTime**" type. This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatDateTime) shows us the method `formatDateTime()` response a value in string.
[image]

So when we insert the value from method `formatDateTime()`, it will insert a string into the storage table. It seems there is a bug in display of azure portal, it shows the type is "**DateTime**". But if we open the table storage in "**Azure Storage Explorer**" but not on Azure portal, we can find the `TimeOfCreation` of new inserted record is in "**String**" type.
[image]

For this requirement, it's difficult to get a "**DateTime**" type value in logic app and insert it into table storage. We can just insert a string. But we can edit the type after insert the new record to table storage. We can do it on Azure portal or in "**Azure Storage Explorer**". If do it on Azure portal, just click "**edit**" the record and click "**Update**" button without do anything(because the type already show as "DateTime"). If do it in "**Azure Storage Explorer**", just change the type from "**String**" to "**DateTime**" and click "**Update**". After that, we can query the records by "TimeOfCreation" >= Last 365 days success.

The bad thing is, we can just do it manually on each inserted record. We can't solve this problem in logic app or batch update the type(on portal or in explorer). If you want to batch update the type, you can query all of the new inserted records by this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities) (use $filter to filter timestamp). And then get each record's `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`, and loop them. Use this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/update-entity2) to update the column `TimeOfCreation` type.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  I was already looping through a number of records and adding them to the table storage so the extra step to update the column type worked a treat!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To insert `DateTime` type of date use odata.type property (refer below sample) and it works.

```
{  
   "Address":"Mountain View",  
   "Age":23,  
   "AmountDue":200.23,  
   "CustomerCode@odata.type":"Edm.Guid",  
   "CustomerCode":"c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a79-3e9149a57833",  
   "CustomerSince@odata.type":"Edm.DateTime",  
   "CustomerSince":"2008-07-10T00:00:00",  
   "IsActive":true,  
   "NumOfOrders@odata.type":"Edm.Int64",  
   "NumOfOrders":"255",  
   "PartitionKey":"mypartitionkey",  
   "RowKey":"myrowkey"  
}
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#property-types

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/inserting-and-updating-entities