# How to put value as DateTime in Azure Table from Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

I have a Logic App that should store data in Azure Table. Everything worked fine until I realized that one of my properties that should be stored as DateTime is stored as String.

The problem is that some other application is doing queries periodically on data in the table and it expects to find DateTimes there:

```cs
var query = new TableQuery<UserEntity>().Where(
    TableQuery.CombineFilters(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate(
                nameof(UserEntity.AccessEndTime),
                QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual,
                DateTime.SpecifyKind(queriedDate, DateTimeKind.Utc)),
            TableOperators.And,
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate(
                nameof(UserEntity.AccessEndTime),
                QueryComparisons.LessThan,
                DateTime.SpecifyKind(queriedDate.AddDays(1), DateTimeKind.Utc))));
```

Basically, my C# app is looking for users who have their `AccessEndTime` property value set to some specific day.

Unfortunately, since the Logic App writes the value as a string, my query does not return any data.

Here's a part of my Logic App:

[image]

First I create an `object` with the proper data as JSON and then I use Insert or Replace Entity block, which used `Body` of that JSON as an entity to be put in the table. As you can see, `AccessEndTime` has a `type: string`. I tried using `type: datetime`, but it just fails with an error (no such type).

I guess I could handle it on the client-side, but then my `UserEntity` will have to have `AccessEndTime` as a `String` and it just doesn't feel right.

What am I missing?

//EDIT
I also found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/inserting-and-updating-entities#constructing-the-json-feed). I tried to put my data like this:

[image]

So, I added explicitly the type of my property. Unfortunately, the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this SO question's response around the same: [Cannot query a DateTime column in Table Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63379621/cannot-query-a-datetime-column-in-table-storage)

*It looks like you could have used `formatDateTime()` as per documentation, but this will not work as described below:*

According to some test, the value is still in **"String"** type but not **"DateTime"** type. This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatDateTime) shows us the method `formatDateTime()` response a value in string.

[image]

So when we insert the value from method `formatDateTime()`, it will insert a string into the storage table. It seems there is a bug in display of azure portal, it shows the type is **"DateTime"**. But if we open the table storage in **"Azure Storage Explorer"** but not on Azure portal, we can find the `TimeOfCreation` of new inserted record is in **"String"** type.

For this requirement, it's difficult to get a "DateTime" type value in logic app and insert it into table storage. We can just insert a string. But we can edit the type after insert the new record to table storage. We can do it on Azure portal or in "Azure Storage Explorer". If do it on Azure portal, just click "edit" the record and click "Update" button without do anything(because the type already show as "DateTime"). If do it in "Azure Storage Explorer", just change the type from "String" to "DateTime" and click "Update". After that, we can query the records by "TimeOfCreation" >= Last 365 days success.

[image]

The bad thing here is, we can just do it manually on each inserted record. We can't solve this problem in logic app or batch update the type(on portal or in explorer). If you want to batch update the type, you can query all of the new inserted records by this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities) (use $filter to filter timestamp). And then get each record's `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`, and loop them. Use this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/update-entity2) to update the column TimeOfCreation type.